# Error in executing insertion query

Tags: php

Isn't this query correct?

```
$insert = INSERT INTO geninfo (S.N, Name, Address, DOB) VALUES ('Suresh','Ratnanagar','1989/04/10');
```

I got following error, please help I am a beginner.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\google.php on line 9

Comment: Enclose them in double quotes `$insert = "INSERT INTO geninfo (S.N, Name, Address, DOB) VALUES ('Suresh','Ratnanagar','1989/04/10')";` because that is a **string!!!**

Comment: You kind of need quotes around a string (in this case your MySQL query)!

Comment: And aren't you supposed to write `[S.N]` as the field name, using brackets, in order to avoid any further error because of the dot in the name of the field ?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Indeed, +1 for this

Answer (score 3):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `geninfo` (`S.N`, `Name`, `Address`, `DOB`) VALUES ('Suresh','Ratnanagar','Missing address here','1989/04/10');";
```

Note that I have also corrected your MySQL query. `S.N` refers to the column named `N` on the table named `S`, which I'm pretty certain is not what you wanted.

Also I just realised you have four columns, but only three values. Fixed that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have no quotes, it should be like this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO geninfo (S.N, Name, Address, DOB) VALUES ('Suresh','Ratnanagar','1989/04/10')";
```

**upd**

It seems you are storing date of birth as a string, not as a `timestamp` (or similar) which is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO geninfo (S.N, Name, Address, DOB) VALUES ('Suresh','Ratnanagar','1989/04/10')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a (NULL or '') for the S.N field and quotes should be given before and after each and every value.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO geninfo (S.N, Name, Address, DOB) VALUES 
           ('', 'Suresh','Ratnanagar','1989/04/10')";
```

Moreover the field name S.N could create problems. Let me know if this works.